# What happens when I access a pointer when it's stored in a vector which is on the stack?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

```cpp
std::vector<object*> objects;
Object* o = new Object();

objects.push_back(o);
```

I want to access `objects[0]`. So, when I access it, is there a pointer to the stack, then the heap? Or, how does this work?

Comment: the question is unclear. A pointer does not carry the information whether it points to a stack or heap allocated object, its just a pointer

Comment: ***So when i acces it is there a pointer to the stack then the heap ?*** It's wherever you put it. I mean whatever pointer you added to your vector will still point in the same place whether it is valid or not. Many new people use `&` and store a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope making the pointer in the vector a dangling pointer.

Comment: Sorry your right i edit my question

Comment: whether the pointed-at object is on the stack or on the heap (or anywhere else for that matter) is a function of how that object was allocated. The `vector` has no control over this.

Comment: A `std::vector` stores its elements in the heap (the dynamic store).  In this case, those elements are pointers.  Those pointers can point to objects on the heap, the stack (automatic store), or static store.  They could also be nullptr pointers (which is okay), or wild pointers (pointing to objects that have been destructed; which is bad to dereference), or uninitialized pointers (arbitrary values; which is also bad to dereference).

Comment: Side note: Storing pointers in `vector`s is usually the wrong path. By storing the objects directly in the `vector` you get more predicable and easier-to-cache access and fewer resource management woes because the `vector` stores everything in one linear block and does all of the management.

Comment: You have to differ between the actual vector *object* and the data contained in the vector. These two are separate and likely stored in very different locations. It's similar with the variable `o` and the object it points to: The variable `o` is stored in one location, and the object it points to in a different location.

Comment: There only one (explicit) pointer in your program, and that pointer is pointing to an object on the heap. `Object* o = new Object();`. But the pointer itself `o` is on the stack. The pointer in the vector is wherever the vector wishes to put it, typically it would be on the heap too.

Comment: @john o is in the stack even tho i called the new keyword? Im sorry im pretty new to computer science

Comment: @user19806240 No you are confusing the pointer, with the object it is pointing to. `o` is on the stack, because that's how you declared it. But the object it is pointing to is on the heap (because of `new`).

Comment: @user19806240 This is a very common newbie confusion, a pointer, and the thing it is pointing to, are two different things. Either, both or neither, could be on the heap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things to unpack here.

First off, let's say you have a `vector<object*>` as you state, and that it is declared with *automatic storage duration*.

```
void f()
{
    // declared with automatic storage duration "on the stack"
    std::vector<object*> my_objects;
}
```

A vector by it's nature stores a contiguous block of memory, which is essentially an array of *n* objects of which it can store, in our example the vector can contain `0..n` `object*`, and the implementation will do that by having a pointer to the first element, and that contiguous block of memory is stored "on the heap".

```
void f()
{
    // declared with automatic storage duration "on the stack"
    std::vector<object*> my_objects;

    // now, my_objects holds 10 object*, and the storage for them
    // is allocated "on the heap"
    my_objects.resize(10);
}
```

It gets interesting because when we're storing `object*` we can't know if it was allocated on the heap *or not*.  Take the following example:

```
void f()
{
    // declared with automatic storage duration "on the stack"
    std::vector<object*> my_objects;

    // now, my_objects holds 2 object*, and the storage for them
    // is allocated "on the heap"
    my_objects.resize(2);

    auto dyn_obj = std::make_unique<object>();
    object auto_obj;

    my_objects[0] = dyn_obj.get();
    my_objects[1] = &auto_obj;
}
```

Above, we have a situation where the *storage for* `my_objects.data()` is allocated on the heap, the `object` pointed to by `my_objects[0]` is allocated on the heap, while the `object` pointed to by `my_objects[1]` *is not*.

As in your example:

```
std::vector<object*> my_objects; // automatic storage duration
object* o = new object;          // o has automatic storage duration
                                 // while what it points to is "on the heap"

 my_objects.push_back(o);        // an allocation will happen
                                 // because my_objects has to
                                 // allocate storage to hold o
```

`my_objects` is "on the stack", as is `o`.  When the scope containing these things is exited, they will be "destroyed".  `my_objects` will run it's destructor, while `o` will "just go away".

The call to `my_objects.push_back()` will allocate memory "on the heap" to hold `1 * sizeof(object*)` ( *at least* ), and will copy the value of `o` into that storage space.